# How to prove that, in the positive orientation, the surface is always on the left?

Tags: vector-analysis, surfaces, parametrization, stokes-theorem, orientation

Let $S$ be an oriented surface with unit normal vector $\mathbf{n}$ and parameterization
$$r(u,v)=(X(u,v),Y(u,v),Z(u,v)),\qquad (u,v)\in D\subset\mathbb R^2.$$

In the context of vector calculus, the definitions below are used to define the "positive orientation" for the border $\partial S$.

> **Definition 1.** We say that $\partial S$ is *positively oriented* provided that its parameterization is given by $r\circ \gamma$, where $\gamma $ is a counterclockwise parameterization of $\partial D$, and the orientation of $S$ is given by $\mathbf{n}=\frac{r_u\times r_v}{\|r_u\times r_v\|}$.

> **Definition 2.**  We say that $\partial S$ is *positively oriented* provided that, as you walk in around $\partial S$ with your head pointing in the direction of $\mathbf{n}$, the surface is always on your left.

Note that definition 1 is the one that works in the proof of Stokes Theorem and definition 2 is geometrically useful in order to find the correct orientation in the exercises.

For some particular cases, where we can calculate $r$, $\gamma$ and $\mathbf{n}$ explicitly, we can see that these definitions agree.

**Question:** How could we justify, in general, that these definitions are equivalent?

Comment: Define "the left" mathematically. I know this is a bit pedantic, but it turns out to be critical for solving the problem.